# How Can I Achieve That PSX Retro Look?

Tags: shaders, unity

I’ve been doing research for a while to do that PS1 retro graphic style look.
But there are only basic tips for starters. (Low resolution, low polygons etc…)

So I’m not looking for “wobbly” vertex effect anymore.
I just want to know how can I do that Unity PSX Shader Shadow/Lighting effect “Color Precision” on Blender.

Exactly this is what I want ---> [image: Sorry for the resolution :(]

I made a few attempts with “ShadertoRGB” but the results are not looks what I want.